# why does Firefox create $HOME/.pulse-cookie, when I am not using pulseaudio

Tags: firefox, pulseaudio

It drives me crazy when programs save their files directly in my $HOME. Even more so, when the files are garbage which has no use. One such example is `$HOME/.pulse-cookie`, which is being created by Firefox every time I play a video in the browser:

```
/home/martin/.pulse-cookie
```

I am not using pulse audio, and I don't have pulse audio installed. Why does Firefox create this file ? Obviously, it is not needed for anything, because everything works fine when i delete it and make my /home immutable (`chattr +i /home/martin`), so that it cannot be created again.

Is there a way to tell Firefox not to create this file ?

A second best solution would be to tell Firefox to create it somewhere else  where it does not bother me (`/tmp/`).

I am using Firefox (Iceweasel) 31 on Debian Wheezy

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/pulse/client.conf`?

Comment: @jasonwryan - yes, I have `/etc/pulse/client.conf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify the file be created in `/tmp` by adding that value to `/etc/pulse/client.conf`:

```
cookie-file = /tmp/pulse-cookie
```

Comment: that's great. But since `/etc/pulse/client.conf` is global, there could be a conflict when multiple users log in. Can I use variable such as `$user` to distinguish the files, i.e.: `/tmp/$user/pulse-cookie`?

Comment: Better to use `.config/pulse/client.conf` in that case...

Comment: `$HOME/.config/pulse/ did not exist. When I create `$HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf`, it has no effect.

Comment: See `man pulse-client.conf`...

Comment: OK, `$HOME/.pulse/client.conf` works.

Answer (score -4):

Your question is very understandable but incorrect.

1. Firefox is not putting .pulse-cookie on your system.
2. .pulse-cookie has nothing to do with pulseaudio.

.pulse-cookie is set directly in your home directory by the web site. They do not enter through the web browser and are not filtered by browser security. They are larger than regular cookies making them more dangerous.

Here is how to stop them.

1. open a terminal in your home directory and run the following commands
2. `rm -R .pulse-cookie`
3. `touch .pulse-cookie` (this creates an empty .pulse-cookie file)
4. `chmod 000 .pulse-cookie` (now the file can not be read, wrote to, or executed)

A new file can not be creates as it already exists. You can not access it as there are no access rights. Anything sent to is lost.

Comment: If FireFox is not creating `.pulse-cookie` can you indicate which program running on the system does? Or is "the web site" just randomly targeting (unprotected) systems connected to the internet?

Comment: This answer is no only extremely wrong (`~/.pulse-cookie` and/or `~/.config/pulse/cookie` are created by pulseaudio *and* documented to be so in `man 1 pulseaudio`) but also extremely misleading by wrongly asserting that that file is some sort of browser cookie. -1.